# Expedia 24 hours cancellation policy if flight departs inside the 24 hour period? Is ChatGPT right?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, expedia

Q: Expedia has a 24 hours cancellation policy, you know about that?

A: Yes, Expedia typically offers a 24-hour cancellation policy for most bookings. [...]

Q: Now what if I book a flight that departs in 18 hours, and Expedia expressly offers me the 24 hours cancellation policy. That means I could cancel the flight 1 hour before departure without penalty, is that right? Or is there some clause that states that cancellation has to be a minimum period before departure? I did not see any such clause.

A: Typically, the 24-hour cancellation policy offered by Expedia and many other travel booking platforms allows you to cancel your reservation for a full refund within 24 hours of booking, regardless of when the actual departure time is. This means that if you book a flight that departs in 18 hours and Expedia offers you a 24-hour cancellation policy, you should indeed be able to cancel the flight without penalty up until 1 hour before departure and still receive a full refund.

[...]

Comment: Utterly incorrect. Why would you trust a chatbot?

Comment: Let me introduce you to a term: [LLM hallucination](https://www.iguazio.com/glossary/llm-hallucination/).  These are "AI" outputs that are "coherent and grammatically correct but factually incorrect or nonsensical".  This is a real problem with these systems.  Because of this, you can't trust them.

Comment: GPT is a *language model*. It works at the level of *language*, being able to produce impressive, grammatically correct sentences. It is in no way a "knowledge engine" and it has zero understanding of contract terms, or anything else for that matter.

Comment: _"Q: Expedia has a 24 hours cancellation policy, you know about that?"_ It appears you fed ChatGPT a flawed statement as fact, and it has built its answer around that...

Comment: ChatGPT can make an infinite number of flawed assertions - debunking them one by one doesn't scale.

Comment: @deceze At their heart these things are just statistical inference engines.  It doesn't even work at the level of language.  It works with multi-dimensional analysis to predict what symbol would be a good fit to come next.  That it produces something akin to language is simply a byproduct of the training data being language texts.

Answer (score 9):

> Is ChatGPT right?

Putting your money on something that ChatGPT says is a really bad idea. Expedia's  [terms of service](https://www.expedia.com/lp/b/terms-of-service) make no explicit mention of a 24 hour cancelation, so it's certainly not true as stated.

Expedia clearly dumps the terms of cancellation on the travel provide. They say

> You do not have an automatic right to cancel or change a booking unless allowed by the relevant Travel Provider under their Rules and Restrictions (which are provided to you before you make a booking).

Which is why you should NEVER BOOK A FLIGHT ON EXPEDIA, unless it's a very significant price different. ALWAYS book directly with the airline.

> That means I could cancel the flight 1 hour before departure without penalty, is that right?

Wrong. The most common 24-hour rule is the one instantiated by the US Department of Transportation which governs most flights from/to the US and US carriers and probably is what ChatGPT is talking about. This rule explicitly restricts the right to cancellation to no less than one week before departure.

The only tickets you can cancel right up to the departure time are fully refundable ones, which are accordingly priced.